# Executing an ElementArrayFinder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am learning protractor and it has thus far been a wild journey because I am also pretty new to Javascript. I learned so far that protractor queues all promises and they can be executed using then().
However, I am now trying to use a filter() on an ElementArrayFinder but it doesn't seem to execute. Only when I preprend it with the return-keyword, the filter get's executed, but then I leave my function and I don't want that.
Can someone help me in understanding this please?

Below my code:

```
it('Select service', function() {
 servicePage.services.filter(function(elem, index) {
      return elem.getAttribute('class').then(function(attribute) {
          console.log('*****' + attribute);
          return attribute === 'service passive';
      });
  });
servicePage.services.get(0).element(by.tagName('input')).click(); 
});
```

When running above, the console log is not performed so I guess the filter function is not being executed. When I do it like below, the filter is executed but then the click() is not performed.

```
it('Select service', function() {
 return servicePage.services.filter(function(elem, index) {
      return elem.getAttribute('class').then(function(attribute) {
          console.log('*****' + attribute);
          return attribute === 'service passive';
      });
  });
servicePage.services.get(0).element(by.tagName('input')).click(); 
});
```

Example3:

```
    it('Select service', function() {
      servicePage.services.filter(function(elem, index) {
        return elem.getAttribute('class').then(function(attribute) {
          console.log('*****' + attribute);
          return attribute === 'service passive';
      });
  }).first().element(by.tagName('input')).click();
});
```

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should catch the element that filter function returns and then perform action on it. [`filter()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) function returns elements that match the criteria you specify in the function. In your case its returning an element that has a `class` attribute `service passive`. If there are more than one elements with same attribute, then you probably have to chain [`get()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) function to perform operation on the required element. Here's how -

```
servicePage.services.filter(function(elem, index) {
      return elem.getAttribute('class').then(function(attribute) {
          console.log('*****' + attribute);
          return attribute === 'service passive';
      });
}).element(by.tagName('input')).click(); //if only one element is returning, click on it
```

OR replace the last line with below line when there are more elements that match the criteria -

```
}).get(1).element(by.tagName('input')).click(); //click the second element in the array of elements returned
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not sure if that is correct. I tried both your suggestions and nothing is logged to the console so I suspect the filter function is not executed.

Comment: The element doesn't get clicked.

Comment: @Homewrecker can you update your question with your html code? or confirm that the locator you are using is proper and returns multiple elements? Thanks

Comment: The locator is correct because when I use the example 3 above, the attribute gets printed to the console, however I get an error stating that the index is out of bound.

Comment: @Homewrecker it throws index out of bound exception because you are using `first()` on the returned element and there are no elements returned with class `service passive`. Can you verify if the class value has exactly that value and no other classes attached to that element? Thanks

Comment: I think I am going to slap one of the developers in the face, they added a space behind the classname so that is why it didn't match. Thanks for the help!